# Растянуть картинку на всю ширину в Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Код:

```
<p><%= image_tag (Photo.find(@event.code_icon)).title ,{width: 100% } %></p>
```

Выдает ошибку:

> syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting ')'

Без знака процента - размер 100 на 100 пикселей.

Надо растянуть на всю ширину страницы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<p><%= image_tag Photo.find(@event.code_icon)).title, style: 'width: 100%;' %></p>
```

А еще лучше - присвойте изображению класс:

```
<p><%= image_tag Photo.find(@event.code_icon)).title, class: 'wide-image' %></p>
```

И стилизуйте в css:

```
.wide-image {
  width: 100%;
}
```